# Installed app icon not visible

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-icons

My app is perfectly running but installed app icon is not visible in the emulator..I had tried everything but still nothing happened.I had read the previous solutions to this problem but none of them worked for me..

Comment: which version of emulator you are using?

Comment: check icon in drawable folder and also check version on emulater like 2.2 4.0

Comment: Paste your manifest file here

Comment: <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>  check this filter in manifest

Comment: this intent filter is there in my manifest- @koutuk

Answer (score 0):

please check your under android manifest file >
 application > android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher